# How to create gun's whir sound?

Tags: gunshot, techniques, sound-design

Hi!

I try to create the whir of a gun sound, like ricochet.
The thing we can hear in movies when the bullet pass just near the camera.
Is someone have an idea about how to create this particular sound?
Some suggestions about the material or effects i can use?

Thanks
Best regards

Alexis

Comment: A ricochet or a pass-by of the bullet?

Comment: a pass-by i think. but it's like a kind of a ricochet sound i think? the whistle of bullet when it pass-by

Comment: @Alexis it sounds like you mean the pass by.  The anatomy of a bullet is usually zip in (pass by), percussive rico hit, zip out (pass by, lower or higher pitch than the zip in)

Answer (score 2):

Try shooting various metal things with a slingshot past a microphone

Answer (score 1):

While actually recording those sounds would be best (see Michael Manzke's post), I've had success in the past with taking various windy sounds and dopplershifting them quite severely. You could even try varispeeding whooshes.

EDIT: If you don't have a doppler plug-in, you can also try automating the frequency of a resonant EQ.

Answer (score 1):

Both Michael & Alex have the right idea. a great start is to use wind tone, add a highly resonant eq to get that sharp singing "note"... then run it through your dopplers as fast as you can. both GRM tools & Waves doppler are very good for this. then I'd also add in some of the flying debris as well. if you set up a mic in a hallway (or long room) you can shoot nuts, bolts, quarters, washers, anything over it (maybe into a towel to soften the impact)... with those two things put together, you should be able to get a wide variety of sounds.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. Your answers are very helpfull.
I've try to process those windy dopplershifting sound with sound of car's engine with high pitch and doppler effect and it works pretty good!!!!